# (web3) Get 'Token Transferred ' log just like etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to get the token transferred log like in etherscan, I am just clue less how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found it, `receipt.logs` are basically the etherscan's **'token transffered'**. In this case I have a `txHash="0x12caf26ee210ebcdaf83a467078eb96be03fc68f8178a1096bea42f047ed44e3"`
[image]

**To get receipt:**

`const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash);`

`receipt.logs` look like this::

```
[
                {
                    "address": "0x178Bf8fD04b47D2De3eF3f6b3D112106375ad584",
                    "topics": [
                        "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                        "0x000000000000000000000000a4a42e925e365792a043f991106a042c774230a2"
                    ],
                    "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007d2e003",
                    "blockNumber": 12748366,
                    "transactionHash": "0x12caf26ee210ebcdaf83a467078eb96be03fc68f8178a1096bea42f047ed44e3",
                    "transactionIndex": 214,
                    "blockHash": "0xdfaab7e0d54c7b596f5a893051b6777e629e40f7e363ad7e5cf098b94df6c7b0",
                    "logIndex": 384,
                    "removed": false,
                    "id": "log_1a879461"
                },
                {
                    "address": "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7",
                    "topics": [
                        "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                        "0x000000000000000000000000a4a42e925e365792a043f991106a042c774230a2",
                        "0x000000000000000000000000178bf8fd04b47d2de3ef3f6b3d112106375ad584"
                    ],
                    "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008a8f83f",
                    "blockNumber": 12748366,
                    "transactionHash": "0x12caf26ee210ebcdaf83a467078eb96be03fc68f8178a1096bea42f047ed44e3",
                    "transactionIndex": 214,
                    "blockHash": "0xdfaab7e0d54c7b596f5a893051b6777e629e40f7e363ad7e5cf098b94df6c7b0",
                    "logIndex": 385,
                    "removed": false,
                    "id": "log_2e1367e7"
                }
            ]
```

Important fields in this are::

1. `address` => Token/Contract address
2. `topics` => `token.method`, `from` => `to`
3. `data` => amount in that token

So every detail is in HEX.. once you decode just like you want

```
{
                "address": "0x178bf8fd04b47d2de3ef3f6b3d112106375ad584",
                "method": "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                "from": "0x0",
                "to": "0xa4a42e925e365792a043f991106a042c774230a2",
                "amount": 131.260419,
                "token_name": "uUSDT"
            },
            {
                "address": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
                "method": "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
                "from": "0xa4a42e925e365792a043f991106a042c774230a2",
                "to": "0x178bf8fd04b47d2de3ef3f6b3d112106375ad584",
                "amount": 145.291327,
                "token_name": "USDT"
            }
```

Comment: how do you decode the HEX details please? I've been struggling to do it!

Comment: Super Easy! use ethereum_input_data_decoder  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-input-data-decoder